# Artin's Algebra, Exercise 2.4.11. (1st edition)

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, solution-verification, cyclic-groups

I have been working through Artin's algebra book. Here's a simple exercise, but I want to make sure I am not missing anything important.

> Let $(G,\cdot)$ be a group and let $x,y \in G$ with orders $m,n$
>   respectively. Now let $H_1 = \left<x\right>$ and $H_2 = \left<y
>  \right>$. Now the exercise asks for the conditions on $m$, $n$, such
>   that
>
> $$ \phi: H_1 \to H_2, x^i \mapsto y^i $$
>
> is a group homomorphism.

If I see it correctly, the only thing I need to ensure for this exercise, is that $\phi$ is well-defined.

In particular, in this case it holds that $\phi(x^kx^l)= \phi(x^{k+l}) = y^{k+l}$ and $\phi(x^k)\phi(x^l) = y^k y^l$. Because $y^{k+l} = y^k y^l$ it thus follows that $\phi(x^kx^l) = \phi(x^k)\phi(x^l)$.

Finally, let's ensure that $\phi$ is well defined.

It then holds that, if $x^i = x^l$, then $y^i = y^l$. But this in turn means that if $m \; \big\vert \; l-i$ then it also holds that $n \; \big\vert \; l-i$. Choosing $l-i=m$ we get that $n \big\vert m$. This is a necessary condition. Similarly we can check that it is also a sufficient condition.

Comment: I did not get why did you consider the map $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow G$

Comment: Thanks, I added an extra paragraph explaining this.

Comment: even then i do not see why do you have to write that map...  Btw, your conclusion is correct..

Comment: Ok thanks again! (Also updated it since with the added paragraph, the additional homomorphism I introduced became redundant).

Comment: fine.. May be you could have made it simple.. to prove $x^i\rightarrow y^i$ is a homomorphism it is enough to prove $x\rightarrow y$ is a homomorphism... Then you do not have to write that $i,l$ etc....

Comment: Oh, nice, it actually took me some time to understand what you mean. So basically to define a homomorphism on a cyclic group, one just has to define its value on a generator.

Comment: Yes... it would be sufficient